# Javascript - strange math output

Tags: javascript, math

This is my JavaScript:

```
function straava() {
    var input = document.getElementById('input').value
    var r1 = document.getElementById('r1').value
    var r2 = document.getElementById('r2').value
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = r2 / (r1 + r2) * input;
}
```

Given values:

```
input = 5
r1 = 1000
r2 = 1000
```

The expected output is `2.5`, but this function produces `0.0004999500049995`. Why is that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript

Comment: You're working with strings. Use [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) appropriately. Also read the questions Arun linked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variables are strings. So here is what happens:

```
"1000" / ("1000" + "1000") * "5";
"1000" / "10001000" * "5";
// 0.0004999500049995
```

The `+` (addition) operator concatenates strings instead of adding them, hence the incorrect result.

Convert your "numbers" to Number; using `parseInt` / `parseFloat` functions, the (unary) `+` operator or `Number` function:

```
var input = parseInt(document.getElementById('input').value, 10);
var r1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('r1').value, 10);
var r2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('r2').value, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not parsing the values to numbers, so it does the calculations on the strings. This happens because getting element values, through the use of `.value`, will return type *string*.

```
function straava() {
   var input = parseInt(document.getElementById('input').value);
   var r1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('r1').value);
   var r2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('r2').value);

   document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = r2 / (r1 + r2) * input;
}
```

Below is an example of the different outputs, using both strings and ints.

```js
function straava(p1, p2, p3) {
    var input = p1 //document.getElementById('input').value
    var r1 = p2 //document.getElementById('r1').value
    var r2 = p3 //document.getElementById('r2').value

    return (r2 / (r1 + r2) * input);
}

document.getElementById('output1').innerHTML = straava('5','1000','1000');
document.getElementById('output2').innerHTML = straava(5,1000,1000);
```

```html
Using strings as parameters: <span id="output1"></span><br/>
Using integers as parameters: <span id="output2"></span>
```